For any $E\in\sigma(\mathbb{A})$ and $\epsilon>0$ there's $\{A_n\}\subset\mathbb{A}$ such that $A:=\cap A_n\subset E$ and $\mu(E\setminus A)<\epsilon$
Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and $\mathbb{A}\subseteq\Sigma$ an algebra on $X$. Denote by $\sigma (\mathbb{A})$ the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ generated by $\mathbb{A}$. Prove that for any $E\in \sigma (\mathbb{A})$ and $\varepsilon >0$ there is $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq \mathbb{A}$ such that $A:=\cap _{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n\subseteq E$ and $\mu (E\setminus A)<\varepsilon $.
This property is stated in the proof of the 1.12.4. Proposition of the book "Measure Theory" by V.I. Bogachev.

I know that if the restriction $\mu|_{\mathbb{A}}$ is a $\sigma$-finite premeasure then for all $E\in\sigma(\mathbb{A})$ we have
$$\mu (E)=\inf \left\{\mu (\cup _{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n):\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq \mathbb{A}\wedge E\subseteq \cup _{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n\right\}.$$
Therefore, it's easy to obtain the desired result if $\mu$ is a finite measure. But I don't know how to prove the general case.

Is $\mu$ Lebesgue measure here?

@anotheruser No. $\mu$ denotes any measure.

What if you decompose the space into disjoint finite measure spaces $X=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k$ and generate a sequence $A_{k,n}$ for each set $X_k \cap E$?  Given $\epsilon >0$, you can produce $A_{k,n}$ such that $A_k=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{k,n} \subseteq E\cap X_k$ and $\mu (E\setminus A_k) < \frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$.

@anotheruser But I’m not assuming that $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure.

I was gonna say use some sort of $\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}$ trick tbh..
